# How to use an already bound key in the code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to use my Tab key to validate the value inserted into a textbox. I also want my Tab key to move on to the next textbox if the validation went well.

So I have my XAML file:

```
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=DVM_Positive_ReadOut}" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="400"  Width="602" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Height="80">
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" FontSize="25" Content="DVM Positive Readout" Width="290"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CodeDigit}" x:Name="DVM_Positive_ReadOut"  Width="300" Height="50" IsReadOnly="{Binding Positive_ReadOnly}" Text="{Binding DVM_Pos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding ValidateReadOnly}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DVM_Positive_ReadOut}"/>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Height="80">
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" FontSize="25" Content="DVM Negative Readout" Width="290" />
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CodeDigit}" x:Name="DVM_Negavtive_ReadOut" Width="300" Height="50" IsReadOnly="{Binding Negative_ReadOnly}" Text="{Binding DVM_Neg, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding ValidateReadOnly}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DVM_Negavtive_ReadOut}"/>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel >
                <Button Content="Enter" FontSize="25" Width="300" Height="50" Margin="50">
                    <Button.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ValidateInsert}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EnterButton}"/>
                    </Button.InputBindings>
                </Button>
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" FontSize="25" Content="{Binding TestGroupLabel}" Width="290" />
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
```

As you can see at line 7, I bound the Tab key to ValidateReadOnly which is used in my ViewModel.
Now I also want to use my Tab key to switch between textboxes. So I wrote in my code behind file:

```
 private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            TraversalRequest tRequest = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            UIElement keyboardFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

            if (keyboardFocus != null)
            {
                keyboardFocus.MoveFocus(tRequest);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that I cannot use my Tab key for the code in my code-behind file because I have bound the Tab key to ValidateReadOnly in my ViewModel.

Yes, I could write the focus code from my code-behind file in my ViewModel with the validation code, but I found it hard to work with focus in the ViewModel.

Comment: Could you change the UpdateSourceTrigger on your TextBoxes to LostFocus? Then you could run the validation in the setter of the property and if it failes throw an exception. You can then handle that exception via WPF or create a custom ValidationFailed style.

Comment: Don't ever even contemplate doing anything with focus in your ViewModel. The ViewModel shouldn't know that the concept of focus exists. UI-specific stuff like that belongs in view/codebehind.

Comment: That's not a good design.  Let people tab freely between controls.  Let them enter anything they want in those controls.  Implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in your ViewModel to inform the user that they have entered incorrect information.  Prevent them from submitting this incorrect info by examining the properties of the INDEI interface in your submit code.  Blocking tabbing because someone entered incorrect information would be frustrating to the user and is not a conventional UI pattern.

Comment: @Will The only thing my Tab button does is check if the user typed 6 characters and then enable the following textbox and disable the current textbox. At least, that is what I want it to do.

Comment: The disabling bit is what concerns me.  But if I wasn't clear on your intent I'm sorry.  Questions--*check if the user typed 6 characters* in any textbox, or in a particular one?  Because if it is a particular one, you can perform these checks in a value changed event handler.